# Keep Offset shortcut question

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have two bones and I want to make an offset from one to to the root. What is the shortcut?

Thx

Comment: So you want the first bone root to snap in position with the other bone root? As in having their roots be in the same space?

Comment: The bones are separated. But I need to connect them. With a offset. What is the shortcut

Comment: Im talking about the spaced line between the bones.

Comment: Do you mean making connecting them by hierarchy? (Making one a parent and the other a child)

Comment: yes. that is what I mean.

Comment: Okay, select both bones so that the one you want to be a parent is the active selection, (last one clicked, slightly brighter yellow), and press Ctrl+P, and then select Keep Offset. This should work I think.